# When I generate the src of an img tag, using php, it strips the forward slash at the end of the tag. Anyone come across this before?

Tags: php, url, image, src

If I have the path to an image stored in `$thumbPath` and I put that as the img tag's src it strips the end "/" from the tag. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

```
<img src="<?php echo $thumbPath; ?>" /> 
// <img src="path/to/file/foo.jpg">
```

Thanks

Comment: It will not, period. There is another implementation issue here, possibly a templating engine or the program you're using to check the source doesn't provide the raw source, but a processed one.

Comment: How did you notice it is stripped away? Viewing HTML source in your browser? Or maybe using Firebug?

Comment: Where are you looking at the generated source? Most likely whatever app/browser you're using is "helpfully" cleaning up the source for you. PHP will not add/remove anything from your output without you having told it to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems very unlikely that this is the location of the problem.  "echo" is not semantically aware.  It's much more likely that the error exists in whatever code is generating `$thumbPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a test to show that Wrikken et al. are correct:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$thumbPath = 'path/to/file/foo.jpg';
?>

<img src="<?php echo $thumbPath; ?>" /> 

<?php
echo htmlspecialchars(ob_get_clean());

// Output:
// Browser: <img src="path/to/file/foo.jpg" />
// CLI: &lt;img src=&quot;path/to/file/foo.jpg&quot; /&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will **not** strip it. As the `/` is outside the scope of the code you have provided us with. The source of the problem is something else, without any more info I can't help you.